# What is the meaning of かけてきた

Tags: grammar, particle-に, て-form, sentence

I am confused by this part にかけてきた. Can someone explain to me?

この曲を給食のときにかけてきた放送委員

Comment: Do you have more context? I feel that the speaker is not emotionally neutral toward 放送委員 when s/he uses this construction in this kind of sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「この曲{きょく}を給食{きゅうしょく}のときにかけてきた放送委員{ほうそういいん}」

「曲をかける」 means "***to play a song/tune on the stereo/CD player, etc.***".

In this case, the music is being played on the broadcasting system in a school during lunch time.

The music "reaches" the students while eating; therefore, it is described as 「かけて**くる**」 from their perspective, which becomes 「かけて**きた**」 in the past tense.

「この曲を給食のときにかけてきた」 is a relative clause that modifies the 「放送委員」.

> "The broadcast committee member(s) who played this song during the school lunch time."